# How to find the CPU time in Tez query execution?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hdfs, tez

I am currently testing time execution for tables stored in HDFS using both MapReduce and Tez.
In MapReduce, I can easily see the CPU time taken for the process.

MapReduce example

[image]

I am not clear on the results shown for Tez query.

Tez example

[image]

Can someone please explain the two times shown in the images? And where can I find the CPU time for Tez query.

EDIT - I found out that the time is logged as vcore-seconds which is the number of cores multiplied by number of seconds that each core runs. Is there any other metric which can be used?

Comment: Why can't you just look at yarn UI(RM web application) using appId? It's usually located at http://rmHostIp:8088

Comment: @MaxNevermind I digged around and found the value for 'yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address' in the yarn-default.xml file.
Thanks for your comment. It made me push to look for the correct port.